# Aligning a button center middle (long text)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align a button in the middle of a scalable/responsive div. The problem is, the button isn't actually centered here. What am I missing? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMxty/117/)

```
div{
     text-align: center;  
}
button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `position: absolute;` for centering elements, you need to negate the `margin` which are half of the size of the `absolute` positioned element. So say if your `button` is `100px` in `width` you need to negate `margin-left: -50px;`

So in your case, am hardcoding `250px` of the `width` so I negated `-125px`, same goes for `height` as well, if the `height` of the element is say `30px` use `margin-top: -15px;`

```
button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
    width: 250px;

    /* Use height as well if you need so, along with margin-top which 
       will have 1/2 of the negative value of the elements height  */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pMxty/118/)

---

The other way to achieve this is to use `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align` set to `middle`

---

On the other hand, if you do not want to use negative `margin` you can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) as well

```
button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; /* Use calc here too if you define height */
    left: calc(50% - 125px); /* Half of the elements width */
    width: 250px;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/pMxty/120/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/MYNe4/)**

```
button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:25%;
    width:50%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reduce the height/ width of the button from it's position as well.
Try this

```
button{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -112px;
    margin-top: -25px;
}
```

Fiddle 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pMxty/119/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pMxty/122/

a Bit of jQuery resolves it.

HTML

```
<div>
    <button>Load my random useless data</button>
</div>
```

css

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

jQuery

```
function place()
{
    var a = $("div").outerWidth() / 2,
    b = $("button").outerWidth() / 2;
$("button").css({
    "left": (a - b)
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
place();
$(window).resize(function(){
place();
});
});
```